# Better way to return values from split

Tags: ruby

I need to parse a field from a CSV column which is a string:

```
TXDAT - SnpRespData_SC or SnpRespData_SC_PD (7)
```

I need to extract:

```
type_0 = SnpRespData
resp_0 = SC
pd_0 = 0
type_1 = SnpRespData
resp_1 = SC
pd_1 = 1
```

from this string. I want to pass the whole string to a function and be able to return these six values.

The string could be any of the following:
a) TXDAT - SnpRespData_SC_PD
b) TXRSP - SnpResp_SC
c) TXDAT - SnpRespData_SC or SnpRespData_SC_PD (7)
d) TXRSP - SnpResp_UC or TXDAT - SnpRespData_UC_PD (7)

So I created a function which receives this string and returns the following:
def map_rxsnp_transaction(rxsnp_transaction)
   tx_dat = []
   tx_rsp = []
   case rxsnp_transaction
       when (/SnpRespData.*SnpRespData/)
           tx_dat = rxsnp_transaction.split(/or/)
           (tx_dat_0, dat_0_resp, dat_0_pd) = tx_dat[0].split(/_/)
      (tx_dat_1, dat_1_resp, dat_1_pd) = tx_dat[1].split(/_/)
      return [tx_dat_0, dat_0_resp, dat_0_pd, tx_dat_1, dat_1_resp, dat_1_pd]
    when (/SnpResp.*SnpRespData/)
      (tx_rsp, tx_dat) = rxsnp_transaction.split(/or/)
      (tx_rsp, rsp_resp, rsp_pd) = tx_rsp.split(/_/)
      (tx_dat, dat_resp, dat_pd) = tx_dat.split(/_/)
      return [tx_rsp, rsp_resp, rsp_pd, tx_dat, dat_resp, dat_pd]
    when (/SnpRespData_{1}/)
      return rxsnp_transaction.split(/*/)

    when (/SnpResp*{1}/)
      return rxsnp_transaction.split(/_/)
    end
 end

Function call:
(tx_rsp[0],tx_rsp[1],tx_rsp[2],tx_rsp[3],tx_rsp[4],tx_rsp[5]) = map_rxsnp_transaction table_col[5]

Just wondering if I can optimize this code better...don't like the way it

Comment: Please format your code by clicking `{}` in the editor. Your question is also very unclear. What have you tried so far? SO is not the place to ask "how do I do XYZ", _without_ error messages or previous attempts you made

Comment: Could the string be  `"TXDAT - SnpRespData_SC_PD (7) or SnpRespData_SC"`? If 'yes', what would be the desired values of the six variables?

Comment: Are you looking for the string `"SnpRespData"` or is the string to be identified in some other manner?  For example, `"TXDAT"`, `"-"`, `"or"` or `"(..)"` could be keywords to guide the search.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking for a specific string, namely, `"SnpRespData"`. If so, you could do this:

```
str = "TXDAT - SnpRespData_SC or SnpRespData_SC_PD (7)"

f, l = str.scan(/SnpRespData\w+/).sort
  #=> ["SnpRespData_SC", "SnpRespData_SC_PD"] 
type_0, resp_0, pd_0 = f.split('_') << 0
  #=> ["SnpRespData", "SC", 0] 
type_1, resp_1, pd_1 = f.split('_').first(2) << 1
  #=> ["SnpRespData", "SC", 1]

type_0 #=> "SnpRespData" 
resp_0 #=> "SC" 
pd_0   #=> 0 

type_1 #=> "SnpRespData" 
resp_1 #=> "SC" 
pd_1   #=> 1
```